# Sample code or documentation on reading AppConfig under AirWatch

Tags: android, app-config, airwatch

I am developing an Android (and iOS) application for a client. The app is installed on devices with AirWatch, and I  need to be able to read AppConfig parameters set by the AirWatch console.

I was able to do this on the iOS - quite simple. But not on Android.

Anyone knows how this is done?
Can you point me to sample code/tutorial/documentation?

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.appconfig.org/android/ and https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html.

Implementation in Android is harder than on iOS, and  the restrictions must be validated by updating the app on Google Play Store (or Android for work private store).